# Angular use currency and number pipes together

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template, angular-pipe

Using Angular
I ve this in my component

```
export class AppComponent {
  currency = 'EUR';
  amount = 312.562;
```

I want to display my amount with my currency in this format within my template

```
312.562 -> €000,000,312.562
```

i ve tried this :

```
{{ amount | number: '9.2' | currency: this.currency }}
```

But i ve this error

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '000,000,312.562 is not a number' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'
```

So , how may i juste preppend the currency symbol without treating it as a valid number ?

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currency pipe works with some further parameter as you can see from its signature:

```
transform(
  value: number|string|null|undefined, currencyCode: string = this._defaultCurrencyCode,
  display: 'code'|'symbol'|'symbol-narrow'|string|boolean = 'symbol', digitsInfo?: string,
  locale?: string)
```

So you could simply use the following in your template:

```
{{ amount | currency: this.currency:'symbol':'9.3' }}
```

(I am not sure if you really want 9.2 or 9.3, but initially you said you would want to have this €000,000,312.562. So it would be 9.3)